# System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: System error

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-10

I'm hosting an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app with IIS 10, and it's throwing the following exception when trying to hit my API's through Postman:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: System error.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationHandler`1.HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, Object resource, IEnumerable`1 requirements)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, Object resource)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

When using Postman on the machine running the web app, I can make successful HTTP requests and not have any issues.  It seems to only be happening when trying to make external requests, but the error text is extremely unhelpful and I'm not sure where to begin diagnosing.  As far as I can tell, the directory containing the web app project files doesn't have any specific security restrictions and the Application Pool is using an account with sufficient permissions to access and use them.

Has anyone seen error text like this before, or have any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: have you apply any [authrization] filter then remove it and test it in postman

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean here - is your suggestion to add an Authorization Filter, remove that Authorization Filter then try again?

Comment: did you set any Custom Authorize Attribute code in your application?  could you please provide a sample code that causes this issue?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal This exception is actually being returned through the API call when making requests.  There are custom authorization attributes on a few of the controller methods, but this exception is produced regardless of which one is exercised, Authorization Policy or no

Comment: try to enable the .net core std log error by adding this score in the web.config file: `<system.webServer>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet.exe" 
                arguments="..\WebConnectionWebServer\WebConnectionWebServer.dll"
                stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                
                hostingModel="InProcess" />
</system.webServer>`

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this exception was being thrown as a result of an incorrect database connection string.  This particular request checks against a local database to ensure the user exists there.

Strangely enough, I've encountered this same type of issue before (where a database connection string is broken / changed at some point), but the resulting exception was much more specific in its Exception text and stack trace.  The only thing I can't explain here is why the above error is so generic.